# Transfer Commits Between Clones

Tags: git, github, git-clone, fork

I had a simple app and pushed it to git few days ago.Now I am having two clones created from same git repo. So, in total, I have 3 apps/clones. I made **independent** changes in all clones and at some point, I find out that now I have to make such changes which are common in all clones. And it will not be easy to implement these changes manually in all clones.

I want to implement them in one clone and they should effect others as well. I don't know if there is a way but I heard that it is possible. How, I am trying to figure it out.

So if it is possible, then share it with me. 
Thanks

Comment: Since there is a remote repo, why not behave as if the three clones are three different people. They can all pull and push and so in the end the remote repo will have all the changes from all of them.

Answer (score 1):

One repo can add the other two as remote:

```
git remote add ...
```

Once you have done a modification in one repo, you can:

- either push to the other repos,
- or, especially when the push isn't a fast-forward one, go to a destination repi, and do a git fetch, or git pull, in order to merge that new commit.

Comment: And he doesn't need them to be on different machines? That's what I was in doubt about when I suggested using the remote he already has.

Comment: @matt no, the remote repos can be anywhere, including your local machine. The url would be a simple path.

Comment: But I have made changes to them and there are only few common features in my clones. Don't you think it will have a negative effect?

Comment: @codeBug no. I would recommend pulling (instead of pushing), in order to merge in the destination repo, and control that way what you integrate.